# How does the Dutch academic culture compare to other countries in Europe?

Tags: academic-life, netherlands

I am Dutch, but have only studied in the Netherlands for my undergraduate degree. I am now applying to assistant professorships. The places where I have been for my PhD and afterwards were quite relaxed; essentially there was not a worry in the world. Obviously that changes as you get loaded with more and more responsibilities in a faculty job, but that is not what my question is about.

From the popular media, I get the impression that Dutch academia is tough: pressure to publish, pressure to get grants, internal political games, etc. Is this indeed the case? How does it compare to other countries in Europe? How should I weigh this into the equation when applying for assistant professorship?

Comment: I posted an answer in the hope that it may help you, but I also voted to close this question because it is nearly impossible to answer clearly (see answer)

Comment: What you write could also be written about an R1 in the US. It sounds familiar.

Comment: The answers below give some very clear information, which is much appreciated! The point where I am coming from is reading news websites in both The Netherlands and the UK, where in my experience problems in academia (amongst faculty) gets vastly more attention in The Netherlands compared to the UK. But I am genuinely positively surprised with the experiences shared below, and they also give me a good handle on what to discuss with a potential future employer.

Comment: Im Dutch and moved to US. The salary is really low however you are required to publish in Q1 each year. So difficult if you dont have funding

Comment: @looktook Comparing US and Dutch salaries means to compare apples and oranges, since both countries have very different costs of living. By European standards, the Netherlands pay well (with the exception of PhD students, whose pay is really not that great).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Is the pay for PhD students in the Netherlands really that bad compared to other European countries? I thought that the legal minimum in the CAO ([See here, in column P](https://vsnu.nl/files/documenten/CAO/salarisschalen_per_1_juli_2021.pdf), the rows roughly correspond to the year for PhD students), isn't that bad. I believe that e.g. in France, postdocs are at times paid less than this.

Comment: @Discretelizard 2.4K€ entry salary is not catastrophic, but not great either. My personal reference points are Germany and Sweden. In Germany, the entry salary is around 4K€ (assuming a full-time position, the chances for which are admittedly field-specific). In Sweden, it's around 3K€. The Netherlands also have the highest taxes of these three (although all three are in the same ballpark).

Comment: What are you talking @lighthouse keeper ? Netherland is 100x times expensive than USA

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm an assistant professor in the Netherlands with previous experiences in other European countries. I fully agree with everything that @Louic writes in his answer. I can especially emphasize the point that the culture between different universities and even departments in the same university can vary a lot.

Additional points:

1. Hierarchies in departments can be particularly "pyramid-like". In particular, the term "assistant professor" is often taken more literally than in other countries, and it's quite common that people stay at the tenured assistant professor level for their whole career. One aspect is that assistant professors often cannot supervise their own PhD students, but need the formal involvement of a full professor who gets the main credit for the supervision.
2. On the positive side, the overall funding situation seems to be particularly nice compared to other countries, especially with regard to the direct flow of money from the country to the universities. For example, the newly hired assistant professors at my department got a package with a PhD student included, which I have not seen in any other countries.
3. The teaching year is relatively long compared to other countries. There is hardly any break between fall and spring semester, and with about 6 weeks, the summer break is relatively short as well. Many professors take 3 or 4 weeks of summer vacation, which can give the impression that things are particularly relaxed.

Overall, if you find a position in a good place, you can absolutely have a very positive experience. As a tenure-tracker, I benefit from a very comfortable teaching load (20% in the first three years!). My tenure criteria are very clear and quantified, which reduces the potential for arbitrariness, and I have a department head who's a genuinely good person.

Comment: The restriction in the first point was weakened in 2017: Assistant Professors can now also be supervisors for PhD students, as long as the examination committee finds them qualified enough. I don't know how common that is, but it is in principle possible nowadays.

Comment: @AlexanderWolters Does this apply to all of the Netherlands? I've heard that some universities/departments have recently allowed for Associate Professors to be PhD supervisors, but there are still universities/departments that don't. I have never heard likewise for Assistant Professors.

Comment: The possibility does apply to all universities: https://www.eerstekamer.nl/behandeling/20170717/publicatie_wet_2/document3/f=/vkfyb4i7plzl.pdf
See the bottom of page 6, Article 7.18.4. As I said, I have no idea whether any University actually makes use of that though.

Comment: What is the tenure-track system in the Netherlands?  I didn't think the tenure-track system was common in Europe.

Comment: @Kimball That could easily be a question of its own. Within the last 15 or so years, the tenure-track system has been widely established in Europe, but the countries differ in their degree of adoption. In the Netherlands, it's indeed the standard setup for new assistant professors. In contrast, German universities are notorious for offering fixed-term, non-tenure-track assistant professorships.

Answer (score 18):

I think this question cannot be answered with a clear answer, but I will try to help because I think my experience may be useful: I am from The Netherlands and got my MSc there. My PhD and Postdoc experience was in France (2 universities) and the UK (2 universities).

- Cultures vary per university, not only per country
- Political games are everywhere
- Pressure to publish and to get grants is worldwide
- If anything, I think there are *less* political games in The Netherlands compared to most other European countries, but I may be biased a little.

You should probably be happy with an assistant professorship anywhere: they are hard to get throughout Europe, even with an excellent CV and publication record, although (obviously) positions in less prestigious universities are less competitive.

Answer (score 3):

From my subjective experience the Netherlands does very well in genuinely trying to find the best applicant for the position advertised. There are less situations of say a generic postdoc advertisement but internally it is already decided that the position will go to professor X's lab regardless of quality of applications or even positions that are publicly advertised although in practice it is already decided who is going to get it.